# Student requesting help interpreting Lavaan output Parallel Multiple Mediation

Tags: r, output, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

I am using a **parallel multiple mediation model** path analysis of manifest variables to analyze the data for my master's thesis. This is my first time conducting path analysis, and my PI is unfamiliar with R, so I'm on my own. I'm hoping I could get some **help interpreting my input and answering some questions** that have come up during this process.

[Path diagram of my model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aq4mM.jpg)

**Here is my model specification code:**

```
#### PARALLEL MULTIPLE MEDIATION MODEL ####

#Recoding Variables for Parallel Multiple Mediation Model specification
#SDO and Power are independent variables recoded as X1 and X2
impdata$X1 <- impdata$sdo.scores
impdata$X2 <- impdata$pow.scores
#Empathy, Reciprocity, Paternalism, Colourblindess, the mediators, are M1, M2, M3, and M4 respectively
impdata$M1 <- impdata$empath.scores
impdata$M2 <- impdata$recip.scores
impdata$M3 <- impdata$pat.scores
impdata$M4 <- impdata$colour.scores
#Autonomy Support and Talk with Family are dependent variables recoded as Y1 and Y2
impdata$Y1 <- impdata$autonomysupport
impdata$Y2 <- impdata$talkfamily

myModel <- '
#direct effects
Y1 ~ b1 * M1 + b2 * M2 + b3 * M3 + b4 * M4 + c1 * X1 + c3 * X2
Y2 ~ b5 * M1 + b6 * M2 + b7 * M3 + b8 * M4 + c2 * X1 + c4 * X2

#mediators
M1 ~ a1 * X1 + a5 * X2
M2 ~ a2 * X1 + a6 * X2
M3 ~ a3 * X1 + a7 * X2
M4 ~ a4 * X1 + a8 * X2

#indirect effects
indirect1 := a1 * b5
indirect2 := a2 * b6
indirect3 := a3 * b7
indirect4 := a4 * b8
indirect5 := a5 * b1
indirect6 := a6 * b2
indirect7 := a7 * b3
indirect8 := a8 * b4
indirect9 := a1 * b1
indirect10 := a2 * b2
indirect11 := a3 * b3
indirect12 := a4 * b4
indirect13 := a5 * b5
indirect14 := a6 * b6
indirect15 := a7 * b7
indirect16 := a8 * b8

# total effect (C)
#autonomy support
total1 := c1 + (a1 * b1) + (a2 * b2) + (a3 * b3) + (a4 * b4)
total2 := c3 + (a5 * b1) + (a6 * b2) + (a7 * b3) + (a8 * b4)
#communication
total3 := c2 + (a1 * b5) + (a2 * b6) + (a3 * b7) + (a4 * b8)
total4 := c4 + (a5 * b5) + (a6 * b6) + (a7 * b7) + (a8 * b8)

# covariates
M1 ~~ M2
M2 ~~ M3
M2 ~~ M4
M1 ~~ M4
M1 ~~ M3
M3 ~~ M4
'

#bootstap CI's
require("lavaan")
fit <- sem(myModel,
           data= impdata,
           se = "bootstrap",
           bootstrap = 5000)

#obtaining more fit measures
summary(fit, fit.measures=TRUE,
        standardize=TRUE,
        rsquare=TRUE,
        estimates = TRUE,
        ci = TRUE)
```

**Lavaan Output**
I have included my output as images to increase readability
[Model fit indices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toUw2.jpg)[Regressions, Covariances, Variances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w14jn.jpg)
[Direct and Indirect Effects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3jfb.png)

**My questions:**

- I thought the model I specified was my test model, but the output puts it as the base model. Do I have to specify the base model first?
- Due to the above, how can I report fit indices?
- From my understanding, none of my indirect (mediations) effects were significant, so now I can only report on the regressions?

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you! Emilie :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Can you explain what else have you tried after specifying the model? Did you run `sem(model,data)`? Which kind of error message is shown?

Comment: @hamagust Thank you for the warm welcome :) I have been able to run my model now with some tweaks, but am now confused at interpreting the output. I will update my question to reflect the current code and output. From my understanding, because none of my indirect effects were significant, I can only report on the regressions. However, I am confused regarding fit indices as the output shows my test model as the output model. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi, it is a good practice to ask just one question per post. If you have over one question, you should post them separately. Please, also add the outputs as text (images will end up as link, and do not increase readability). Now, I see most of your questions are more about interpretation. Methodological questions should be asked at [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)... In the attempt to answer your first question (maybe code-related): what you specifically mean by “base model” and “test model”?

Comment: Also, considering the "run my model **now**", and presuming that it means, previously, when you asked initially, you were struggling in running it... It means you are dealing with a new problem. Next time I recommend you to ask a new question (you can delete the older, if you wish), even being the same model, also because new questions are more prone to track more attention...